# reading more than one text file and store the content to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop

i write a c# program that read data from 5 text files and count them according to some given key word

```
        string[] word_1 = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Niyomal N\Desktop\Assignment\Assignment\D1_H1.txt").Split(' ');
        string[] word_2 = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Niyomal N\Desktop\Assignment\Assignment\D2_H1.txt").Split(' ');
        string[] word_3 = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Niyomal N\Desktop\Assignment\Assignment\D3_H2.txt").Split(' ');
        string[] word_4 = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Niyomal N\Desktop\Assignment\Assignment\D4_H2.txt").Split(' ');
        string[] word_5 = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Niyomal N\Desktop\Assignment\Assignment\D5_H2.txt").Split(' ');
        string[] given_doc = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Niyomal N\Desktop\Assignment\Assignment\Given_doc.txt").Split(' ');
```

this is how i read from text files, after reading that i use for loop and if loop to count each word from hose file

```
for (int i = 0; i < word_1.Length; i++)

        {

            string s = word_1[i];


                if ("Red".Equals(word_1[i]))
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(word[i]);

                    h1_r++;
                }
                if ("Green".Equals(word_1[i]))
                {
                    h1_g++;
                }
                if ("Blue".Equals(word_1[i]))
                {
                    h1_b++;
                }

        }
```

this is the loop i used to get the count from one file and its works fine, i did this process 5 times to read all files, my question is how can i read those 5 files using one for loop and store them in a array (count of each key word)

thanks in advance !!

Comment: Are the names of the files important or do you just read all files in that directory?

Comment: Does your first code block compile?! ReadAllText() returns a string, not an array.

Comment: actually the number of text files are important not the file names.i want to get the data from multiple text  files

Comment: Why `arrays` use [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Actually I wonder why you have to store them instead of read, count and dispose...

Comment: yes its compile and gave the correct answers, what i want to do here is i need to stop coding the same loops to read all the five files again and again and i want to get the number of keywords in each file separately and store them in in a array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy pasting code is generally not good. It leads to code violating the Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) rule. Restructure your code:

```
const string path = @"C:\Users\Niyomal N\Desktop\Assignment\Assignment";
string[] files = new string[] { "D1_H1.txt", "D2_H1.txt", "D3_H1.txt", ... };

foreach (string file in files) {
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(path, file);
    //TODO: count words of file `fullPath`
}
```

Storing the word counts in an array is not optimal as you will have to traverse the array for each word you are encountering in a file.
Use a dictionary instead which has a constant lookup time. That's much faster.

```
var wordCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

You can then count the words like this:

```
int count;
if (wordCount.TryGetValue(word, out count)) {
    wordCount[word] = count + 1;
} else {
    wordCount[word] = 1;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

You can test for keywords like this

```
var keywords = new HashSet<string> { "Red", "Green", "Blue" };

string word = "Green";
if (keywords.Contains(word)) {
    ...
}
```

HasSets are as fast as dictionaries.

Be careful with the word casing. `HashSets` are case sensitive by default. If "red" and "Red" and "RED" have to be found alltogehter, initialize the `HashSet` like this:

```
var keywords = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    { "Red", "Green", "Blue" };
```

Comment: how can i use this to count those special keyword i mean i want to count only the  "red" "green " and " blue" key word count in each documents, document can contain words other that that i want to filter the amount of those key words only

Answer (score 2):

LINQ query is your the simplest solution here:

```
var filenames = new[] { "D1_H1.txt", "D2_H1.txt", "D3_H2.txt" };
var words = new[] { "Red", "Green", "Blue" };
var counters = 
  filenames.Select(filename => Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Niyomal N\Desktop\Assignment\Assignment", filename))
           .SelectMany(filepath => File.ReadAllLines(filepath))
           .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new[] { ' ' }))
           .Where(word => words.Contains(word))
           .GroupBy(word => word, (key, values) => new
              {
                 Word = key,
                 Count = values.Count()
              })
           .ToDictionary(g => g.Word, g => g.Count);
```

and then you have dictionary of word counter within all files:

```
int redCount = counters["Red"];
```

If you want to store counters per each file, you can use slightly modified query:

```
var filenames = new[] { "D1_H1.txt", "D2_H1.txt", "D3_H2.txt" };
var words = new[] { "Red", "Green", "Blue" };
var counters =
  filenames.Select(filename => Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Niyomal N\Desktop\Assignment\Assignment", filename))
           .Select(filepath => new
           {
              Filepath = filepath,
              Count = File.ReadAllLines(filepath)
                          .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new[] { ' ' }))
                          .Where(word => words.Contains(word))
                          .GroupBy(word => word, (key, values) => new
                           {
                              Word = key,
                              Count = values.Count()
                           })
                          .ToDictionary(g => g.Word, g => g.Count)
            })
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Filepath, g => g.Count);
```

and then use it accordingly:

```
int redCount = counters[@"C:\Users\(...)\D1_H1.txt"]["Red"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> completeList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

            completeList.AddRange("D1_H1.txt",File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Niyomal N\Desktop\Assignment\Assignment\D1_H1.txt").Split(' '));
            completeList.AddRange("D1_H2.txt", File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Niyomal N\Desktop\Assignment\Assignment\D2_H1.txt").Split(' '));
            completeList.AddRange("D1_H3.txt", File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Niyomal N\Desktop\Assignment\Assignment\D3_H2.txt").Split(' '));
            completeList.AddRange("D1_H4.txt", File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Niyomal N\Desktop\Assignment\Assignment\D4_H2.txt").Split(' '));
            completeList.AddRange("D1_H5.txt", File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Niyomal N\Desktop\Assignment\Assignment\D5_H2.txt").Split(' '));
            completeList.AddRange("D1_H6.txt", File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Niyomal N\Desktop\Assignment\Assignment\Given_doc.txt").Split(' '));


            var result = completeList.GroupBy(r => r.Key).Select(r => new {File = r.Key, Red = r.Count(s => s.Value == "red"), Green = r.Count(s => s.Value == "green"), Blue = r.Count(s => s.Value == "blue") });
            foreach (var itm in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(itm.File);
                Console.WriteLine(itm.Red);
                Console.WriteLine(itm.Green);
                Console.WriteLine(itm.Blue);

            }
```

Comment: i want to get the count of each key word in each file separately and store them in a array.